# Inverse Laplace with square root of s in quotient

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, inverse-laplace

I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of expressions of the form $$\frac{a + b \sqrt{s}}{cs + d\sqrt{s} +e}$$ Even an instance of it like $$\frac{\sqrt{s}}{s + \sqrt{s} +1}$$ perhaps?  There are similar questions previously asked. Is contour integration the only viable approach or is there a solution for a such or more general family already existent in the literature?

Comment: [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+Laplace+transform+sqrt%28s%29%2F%28s%2Bsqrt%28s%29%2B1%29) can't find the solution for the simple case

Comment: Solution for the simple case is $$-\frac{\sqrt[6]{-1} e^{(-1)^{2/3} t} \text{erfc}\left(\sqrt[3]{-1} \sqrt{t}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{(-1)^{5/6} e^{-\sqrt[3]{-1} t} \text{erfc}\left(-(-1)^{2/3} \sqrt{t}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{t}}$$